# Tkinter "_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist" error

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to add an image to a frame in Tkinter but getting the error: `_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist`.
I have a parent class that all of my windows inherit from:

```
class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, name, dimensions):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.dimensions = dimensions
        self.title(self.name)
        self.geometry(self.dimensions)
```

The child class I want to add the image to is shown below(I have taken out some of the functions so that it isn't very long).

```
class Analyze(GUI):
    def __init__(self, name, dimensions):
        super().__init__(name, dimensions)


        conn = sqlite3.connect('invoice_db.db')

        cursor = conn.cursor()

        self.frame1 = LabelFrame(self, text="Analyze Data")
        self.frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

        self.frame2 = LabelFrame(self, text="Graph")
        self.frame2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

        self.choices = ["", "", "", "", ""]

        self.select_type = ttk.Combobox(self.frame1, value=("Credit", "Debit", "Net Profit"))
        self.select_type.current(0)
        self.select_type.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.click_type)
        self.select_type.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.company_list = ["All Companies"]
        cursor.execute("SELECT company_name FROM companies"),
        self.companies = cursor.fetchall()
        for x in self.companies: self.company_list.append(x[0])

        self.select_company = ttk.Combobox(self.frame1, value=self.company_list)
        self.select_company.current(0)
        self.select_company.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.click_company)
        self.select_company.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.start_date_calendar = DateEntry(self.frame1, date_pattern='y-mm-dd')
        self.start_date_calendar.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.start_date_calendar.bind("<<DateEntrySelected>>", self.start_date)

        self.end_date_calendar = DateEntry(self.frame1, date_pattern='y-mm-dd')
        self.end_date_calendar.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.end_date_calendar.bind("<<DateEntrySelected>>", self.end_date)

        self.currency_entry = Entry(self.frame1)
        self.currency_entry.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.show_results_button = Button(self.frame1, text="Show Results", command=self.show_results)
        self.show_results_button.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.go_back_button = Button(self, text="Go Back", command=self.go_back)
        self.go_back_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.create_graph_button = Button(self.frame2, text="Create Graph", command=self.create_graph)
        self.create_graph_button.pack()

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

    def create_graph(self):
        image1 = Image.open("images/hop1.png")
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
        label1 = Label(self.frame2,image=img)
        label1.image = img
        label1.pack()
```

I call the Analyze class in another class like this:

```
class Welcome(GUI):
    def __init__(self, name, dimensions):
        super().__init__(name, dimensions)

        # Create the starting label and buttons
        self.title = Label(self, text="Invoice Organizer", font=("Helvetica", 36))
        self.title.place(relx=.5, rely=.1, anchor="center")

        self.company_button = Button(self, text="Companies", font=("Helvetica", 18), command=lambda: self.select_page("Company"))
        self.company_button.place(relx=.3, rely=.5, anchor="center")

        self.analyze_button = Button(self, text="Invoices", font=("Helvetica", 18), command=lambda: self.select_page("Invoice"))
        self.analyze_button.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")

        self.invoice_button = Button(self, text="Analyze", font=("Helvetica", 18), command=lambda: self.select_page("Analyze"))
        self.invoice_button.place(relx=.7, rely=.5, anchor="center")

    def select_page(self, button):
        if button == "Company":
            new = Company(button, "1000x800")
        elif button == "Invoice":
            new = Invoice(button, "1000x800")
        else:
            new = Analyze(button, "1000x800")
```

Comment: That can be caused by calling `Tk()` more than once in a program.  You haven't shown us enough code to actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I edited the code part now.

Comment: You can't have multiple windows that all inherit from `Tk`, that's exactly the same thing as calling `Tk()` multiple times directly.  You want `Toplevel` as the base class for everything other than the root window.

Comment: Could you explain how can I do that?